# python Logging console and file output contains repeated message

Tags: python, logging, flask, pycharm, python-logging

I have implemented logging for the python-flask project for that i have created one module logging_manager with code -

```
file_formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(filename)s -  %(funcName)s - %(lineno)i - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
console_formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(filename)s -  %(funcName)s - %(lineno)i - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

file_log_level = logging.DEBUG
console_log_level = logging.WARNING
root_logging_level = logging.INFO

logName = "main.log"
fileNamePrefix = settings.ROOT_DIR + '/logs/'
fileMaxBytes = 4e+6
backUpCount = 1
encoding = 'utf8'

def get_logger():

    logger = logging.getLogger(logName)

    filehandler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileNamePrefix + logName,
                                               maxBytes=fileMaxBytes, backupCount=backUpCount,
                                               encoding=encoding)
    filehandler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
    filehandler.setLevel(file_log_level)
    logger.addHandler(filehandler)

    consolehandler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
    consolehandler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
    consolehandler.setLevel(console_log_level)
    logger.addHandler(consolehandler)

    logger.setLevel(root_logging_level)

    return logger
```

and using it in my python scripts by importing a logger from logging_manager.

```
from logging_manager import get_logger
get_logger().error("wrong file type provided")
```

every time it calls get_logger it adds extra one message to it.

my output is(you can see repetition) -

```
2019-10-09 13:42:35,591 - fabric_api.py -  post - 32 - INFO - Fabric classification Model Triggered
2019-10-09 13:42:35,605 - fabric_api.py -  post - 38 - INFO - Started processing file - 7c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png
2019-10-09 13:42:35,605 - fabric_api.py -  post - 38 - INFO - Started processing file - 7c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png
2019-10-09 13:42:35,606 - fabric_api.py -  post - 45 - INFO - saved image to location - E:\1570608755.6064117c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png
2019-10-09 13:42:35,606 - fabric_api.py -  post - 45 - INFO - saved image to location - E:\1570608755.6064117c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png
2019-10-09 13:42:35,606 - fabric_api.py -  post - 45 - INFO - saved image to location - E:\1570608755.6064117c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png
2019-10-09 13:42:46,167 - fabric_api.py -  post - 54 - INFO - Completed fabric detection with result - {'image': '7c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png', 'confidence_score': '0.9986871', 'predicted_class': 'Cotton'}
2019-10-09 13:42:46,167 - fabric_api.py -  post - 54 - INFO - Completed fabric detection with result - {'image': '7c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png', 'confidence_score': '0.9986871', 'predicted_class': 'Cotton'}
2019-10-09 13:42:46,167 - fabric_api.py -  post - 54 - INFO - Completed fabric detection with result - {'image': '7c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png', 'confidence_score': '0.9986871', 'predicted_class': 'Cotton'}
2019-10-09 13:42:46,167 - fabric_api.py -  post - 54 - INFO - Completed fabric detection with result - {'image': '7c6d4400-e002-11e9-984e-a86daadb0edd.png', 'confidence_score': '0.9986871', 'predicted_class': 'Cotton'}
```

I am using pycharm for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake in my code, I had initialized logger inside get_logger(). so, each time I am calling this function, it is creating a new logger instance again and again and my message got passed to each logger.

Following modification solved my problem-

```
logName = "main.log"
fileNamePrefix = settings.ROOT_DIR + '/logs/'
fileMaxBytes = 4e+6
backUpCount = 1
encoding = 'utf8'

logger = logging.getLogger(logName)

filehandler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler(fileNamePrefix + logName,
                                               maxBytes=fileMaxBytes, backupCount=backUpCount,
                                               encoding=encoding)
filehandler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
filehandler.setLevel(file_log_level)
logger.addHandler(filehandler)

consolehandler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
consolehandler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
consolehandler.setLevel(console_log_level)
logger.addHandler(consolehandler)

logger.setLevel(root_logging_level)

def get_logger():

    return logger
```